# Código continua rodando após o fim do jogo

Tags: python

Na linha 10, mesmo que eu escolha a opção 2 para não continuar no jogo, aparece o Fim de jogo mas o código continua rodando.

Na linha marcada (a linha 10), mesmo que eu escolha a opção 2, que deveria ser o fim de jogo, o jogo ainda continua mesmo que eu escolha a opção 2! Alguém sabe me ajudar?

```
print("========TESTE RPG========")
print()
print("========BEM VINDO A ASGARD!========")
print("Você tem certeza que deseja encarar essa jornada?")
a = int(input("Digite '1' para sim ou digite '2' para não!"))
if (a==1):
    print("Boa jornada aventureiro!")
else:
    if(a==2):
        print("Fim de jogo!") # Linha 10.

    else:
        print("Você precisa digitar '1' ou '2'!!!")
    print("Velho Estranho: Vejo que és corajoso jovem guerreiro!")
    print("Velho Estranho: Meu nome é Danagorn!")
    print("Danagorn: Qual é o seu nome meu jovem?")
    nome = input("Eu: Meu nome é:")
    print("Danagorn: Bem, seja bem vindo a Asgard,", nome)
    print("Danagorn: Vejo que estás sem seus equipamentos! Gostaria de se equipar?")
    equip = int(input("Digite '1' para confirmar ação, ou '2' para negar!"))
if (equip==1):
    print("Danagorn: Tome aqui então esta armadura, que com certeza lhe será util!")
    print("Danagorn: Pegue também esta espada e este escudo, lhe serão de grande serventia!")
else:
    if(equip==2):
        print("Danagorn: Não permitirei que você siga em frente sem estar bem equipado!")
        print("Danagorn: Se você não se equipar, receio que não possamos continuar nossa jornada!")
        equip1 = int(input("Digite '1' para se equipar, ou digite '2' para desistir da jornada!"))
        if(equip1==1):
            print("Danagorn: Boa escolha, meu jovem!")
        else:
            print("Danagorn: A sua jornada se encerra aqui!")
            print("Fim de jogo!")
```

Comment: Jovem, ao invés de colocar "resolvido" no título, você deve marcar a resposta clicando no botão que fica abaixo do votos da resposta que você gostou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo porque apesar do código entrar na condição específica, o processamento continua a partir da linha 15. Você precisa interromper a execução do jogo com o seguinte comando:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Adicione logo após a linha:

```
print("Fim de jogo!")
```

Answer (score -1):

Tente algo assim:

```
def ler_input(msg):
    a = 0
    while a != 1 and a != 2:
        a = int(input(msg))
        if a != 1 and a != 2:
            print("Você precisa digitar '1' ou '2'!!!")
    return a == 1

print("========TESTE RPG========")
print()
print("========BEM VINDO A ASGARD!========")
print("Você tem certeza que deseja encarar essa jornada?")

a = ler_input("Digite '1' para sim ou digite '2' para não!")

if a:
    print("Boa jornada aventureiro!")
    print("Velho Estranho: Vejo que és corajoso jovem guerreiro!")
    print("Velho Estranho: Meu nome é Danagorn!")
    print("Danagorn: Qual é o seu nome meu jovem?")
    nome = input("Eu: Meu nome é:")
    print("Danagorn: Bem, seja bem vindo a Asgard,", nome)
    print("Danagorn: Vejo que estás sem seus equipamentos! Gostaria de se equipar?")
    equip = ler_input("Digite '1' para confirmar ação, ou '2' para negar!")
    if equip:
        print("Danagorn: Tome aqui então esta armadura, que com certeza lhe será util!")
        print("Danagorn: Pegue também esta espada e este escudo, lhe serão de grande serventia!")
    else:
        print("Danagorn: Não permitirei que você siga em frente sem estar bem equipado!")
        print("Danagorn: Se você não se equipar, receio que não possamos continuar nossa jornada!")
        equip1 = ler_input("Digite '1' para se equipar, ou digite '2' para desistir da jornada!")
        if equip1:
            print("Danagorn: Boa escolha, meu jovem!")
        else:
            print("Danagorn: A sua jornada se encerra aqui!")
print("Fim de jogo!")
```

A ideia é criar a função `ler_input(msg)` que pergunta para o usuário, insistindo que ele responda 1 ou 2 até ele fazer isso.

O `print("Fim de jogo!")` fica bem no final, fora de qualquer identação para que ele apareça sempre apenas uma vez e somente no fim, independente de quais forem os caminhos a execução do código tome nos passos anteriores.